# Modx php & Template variable

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

Is there a way to do something like that in a snippet : `<?php if ([[+idx]]==1) echo "0";<?`

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to get the value of a template variable, you can use this

```
$id = $modx->resource->get('id');//ID of current resource
$name = $modx->resource->get('pagetitle');//title of current resource
$val = $modx->resource->getTVValue('name_of_tv');//get tv value of current resource by name
$val = $modx->resource->getTVValue($tv_id);//get tv value of current resource by ID
```

To get idx of migx tv you need something like this -

```
<?php
$docid = $modx->resource->get('id'); // id of curent resource
$tvname = 'name_of_your_tv'; // change to yours
$tv = $modx->getObject('modTemplateVar', array('name' => $tvname));
$outputvalue = $tv->renderOutput($docid);
$items = $modx->fromJSON($outputvalue);
$idx = 0; // initialize idx
$output = array();
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    $idx++; // increase idx
    $output[] = print_r($item,1); // test output
}
$outputSeparator = "\n";
$o = implode($outputSeparator, $output); // implode output
return $o;
```

Taken from migx snippet https://github.com/Bruno17/MIGX/blob/master/core/components/migx/elements/snippets/snippet.getImagelist.php

Comment: Thank you, [[+idx]] is the id of a migx item, how can i get this value ?

Answer (score 0):

since you are probably calling your snippet from the resource in question [are you?] you can just pass the idx to the snippet....

```
[[!callMySnippet? &idx=[[+idx]] ]]
```

then in your snippet:

```
$output = '';
$idx = $scriptProperties['idx'];

if ($idx==1) {
$output = "0";
}

return $output;
```

Comment: `([[+idx]]==1)` In snippets modx used pure php and this is caused an error. Maybe you wanted to write `($idx==1)` ?

Comment: @vasis - right - I just copied that from the OP without thinking. edited & fixed.